# Getting Standard Deviation from Range Criteria

Tags: excel-2007

I have this problem getting the Standard Deviation (equiation [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html)). My question is how could I get the sum of ([X interval] - mean) from a set of data wherein a certain criteria(s) is to be followed.

For example, the data is:

```
Gender Grade 
M      36
M      32
F      25
F      40
```

I have acquired N needed in the equation via `COUNTIFS` and acquired the mean via `SUMIFS`. The problem is having the get the sum of the range (X interval minus mean) **without** declaring a cell/column for the said range. In the given example, I would want to get the Standard Deviation of Grade with respect to gender. It would be hard if record 2 gender would be changed to 'F' if I would add column for X interval minus mean.

Any thoughts how this maybe done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little algebra the sd formula can be rewritten as

```
        Ʃ(x²) - Ʃ(x)²/n 
sd = √( --------------- )
              n
```

which can be implemented with `SUMIFS`, `COUNTIFS` and `SUMPRODUCT`

Assuming gender data is in range `A1:A4` and grade in `B1:B4` and criteria in `C1` use

```
=SQRT( (SUMPRODUCT($B$1:$B$4,$B$1:$B$4,--($A$1:$A$4=C1)) -  
       SUMIFS($B$1:$B$4,$A$1:$A$4,C1)^2/COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$4,C1)) /  
       COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$4,C1) )
```

Comment: @pnuts Point (i) correct, (ii) ranges may include or excluse headers, it doesn't matter.  Make it the whole column if you want.  The overall point is the OP asked for a formula to do a _conditional_ standard Deviation without using intermediate results columns. There are no built in functions to do that.